# Zoom A1X to Garage Band

Tags: pre-amp

I've tried to connect my guitar - Zoom A1X - Garage Band to no avail. Do I need things like focusrite, or else?

Comment: Looking at the online manual it seems as though the USB port on this unit is for powering it or for connecting to a computer to use Guitar Lab software for managing effects and patches. It doesn’t mention using it as an audio interface. In that case you will need an audio interface to record into GarageBand. Maybe someone else on this site knows something specific about this unit that can help you.